# Can I command Raspberry Pi 3 from a laptop via Bluetooth?

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

I'm opting to use a script in my laptop coded in Java or Python to send data and commands to a Raspberry Pi 3 via Bluetooth.

I'm working on a swarm robot project and the idea is to have a server-based command and control from laptop.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the phrase "a server-based command and control from laptop"? Seems somewhat contradictory.

Comment: @techraf,  to clarify, the server is an application in the laptop that merge the data from multiple sensors in an industrial environment then send commands to the Rpi 3 via Bluetooth.

Comment: I wonder how this turned out for you? I've gotten  my laptop and pc talking over bluetooth and I connected using bluetoothctl. I can't get the rpi to connect to my pc with bluetoothctl, however. I'm using and rpi 2 model b I bought a long time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Serial Port Profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92255/how-do-i-connect-and-send-data-to-a-bluetooth-serial-port-on-linux) to create virtual serial ports on your laptop. RPi boards could be set up to automatically connect to such ports, giving you console access that can be used to run shell commands or to use your own command protocol.

Note that Bluetooth is [very limited](https://superuser.com/questions/931188/how-many-devices-can-be-hooked-up-to-one-pc-bluetooth-adapter-at-a-time) in terms of simultaneous connections, so your "swarm" will likely consist of 7 devices at most. You could add more BT adapters to your laptop, but then you'll hit interference problems.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry for the answer, i will see what can i do.                                Ps: im using 4 devices so i don't have the problem of the capacity of BT.